# Form doesn't resize smoothly with a timer event

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a grid control at the bottom of my form and it can be shown or hidden if user wants to show/hide it. So one way was to well use AutoSize of the form and change the Visuble property of that grid to true or false,...
But I thought let's make it a little cooler! so I wanted the form to resize a little more slowly, like a garage door! So I dropped a Timer on the form and started increasing the height of the form little by little while the timer ticks...

so something like this when user says show/hide the grid:

```
    timer1.Enabled = true;
    timer1.Start();
```

and something like this on the timer_click event:

```
    this.Height = this.Height + 5;
    if(this.Height -10 > ErrorsGrid.Bottom )
        timer1.Stop();
```

It kind of works but still not perfect. For example it lags at the very beginning, stops resizing like a second and then starts resizing again...So now with this idea in mind what alterations do you suggest I should do to make this thing look and work better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using a `System.Timers.Timer` instead. You can read more about the differences between the available .net timers [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx), but I think your issue comes down to this:

> "[System.Windows.Forms.Timer] events raised by this timer class are synchronous with
>   respect to the rest of the code in your Windows Forms app. This means
>   that application code that is executing will never be preempted by an
>   instance of this timer class..."

This won't be a problem with a System.Timers.Timer. Just be sure to set that object's `SynchronizingObject` to your form so that the elapsed event executes on the UI thread.

Example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(100);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        timer.AutoReset = true;
        timer.SynchronizingObject = this;
        timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
    }

    void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Height += 5;

        if (this.Height -10 > ErrorsGrid.Bottom)
            timer.Stop();
    }

    void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try using this other timer class? Did it help? I kinda made an assumption about which one you were originally using based on it having a `Tick` event.

Comment: Good information, I didn't know this about timers. Will try it as soon as I go to my work laptop. Now on a Mac, can't do VS in it :)